# Pandas conditional column returning the opposite?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, null, conditional-statements

I want to add a third column on a Pandas dataframe which is a conditional, using info from the second if the first is NaN, and from the first in any other cases.

When i use the following code, it simply doesnt work.
BUT, if i change the == to != it works (which didnt make any sense to me since its asking the opposite).

```
def Launch_year_final(row):
    if row['Launch year'] == 'NaN':
        return row['Launch year (filled)']
    else:
        return row['Launch year']

result['Launch year (final)'] = result.apply(Launch_year_final, axis=1)
```

Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: `result['Launch year (final)'] = result['Launch year'].fillna('Launch year (filled)')`

Comment: Did you tried `if row['Launch year'] == np.nan` ?

Comment: @QuangHoang it worked, just had to change inside fillna to result[`Launch year (filled)]. Thanks!! Any idea why my conditionals were returning oposite?

Comment: @Renaud Not yet, i am only using pandas until now, but sure will give it a try.

Comment: @Renaud `np.nan == np.nan` would return False.

Answer (score 0):

`NaN` value a special constant, to validate if something is `NaN` you need to use `pandas.isnan` or `numpy.isnan()`. Another solutions is using `numpy.where()`:

```
import numpy as np
result['Launch year (final)'] = np.where(np.isnan(result['Launch year']), 
                                         result['Launch year (filled)'],
                                         result['Launch year'])
```